# VisualRecognitionV3 new classifier status = failed

Tags: python, classification, ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I have the following Python SDK example code and input image files in Bluemix to create new classifiers. Here is the code:

```
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2016-05-20',api_key=apikey)with 
open('./cars.zip', 'rb') as cars, open('./trucks.zip', 'rb') as trucks:
            print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.create_classifier('Cars', 
            positive_examples=cars, negative_example=trucks), indent=2)) 
            print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.list_classifiers(), indent=2))
```

runlog shows status=failed.

What am I missing?

```
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App {
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "owner": "885160bd-637d-4f8f-b268-fed5df81d672",
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "classifier_id": "Cars_2004369051",
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "created": "2016-06-17T19:50:03.301Z",
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "name": "Cars",
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "classes": [],
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App "status": "training"
17/6/2016 19:50:03  OUT App }
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App {
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App "classifiers": [
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App {
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App "name": "Cars",
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App "classifier_id": "Cars_933017903",
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App "status": "failed"
17/6/2016 19:50:05  OUT App },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This worked for me:

   ```
   import json
   from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 as vr
   instance =vr(api_key='apikey', version='2016-05-20')
   with open('./trucks.zip', 'rb') as trucks, \
       open('./cars.zip', 'rb') as cars:
       visual_recognition.create_classifier('CarsvsTrucks', cars_positive_examples=cars, negative_examples=trucks)
   ```